# GitHub Actions start workflow on pull request multi branch multi environment

Tags: github, yaml, github-actions, workflow, cicd

I am trying to start Github actions workflow jobs with the following conditions, with each condition initiating a separate job:

1. If there is a new pull request to dev branch - deploy infrastructure to dev environment
2. If the code is merged to dev branch - deploy infrastructure to uat environment
3. If there is a new pull request to main branch - deploy infrastructure to staging environment
4. If the code is merged to main branch - deploy infrastructure to production environment

```
on:   
  push:
    branches:
      - dev
      - main   
  pull_request:
    types: [opened, reopened]
    branches:
      - dev
      - main   
  workflow_dispatch:
        
    jobs:
        
          DeployDev:
            name: Deploy to dev
            if: ${{github.ref == 'refs/heads/dev' && github.event_name == 'pull_request'}}
            runs-on: ubuntu-latest
            environment: dev
            more steps follows ......
```

similarly for other matching conditions (separate jobs to run), I am using

DeployUat:

```
if: ${{github.ref == 'refs/heads/dev' && github.event_name == 'push'}}
```

DeployStaging:

```
if: ${{github.ref == 'refs/heads/main' && github.event_name == 'pull_request'}}
```

DeployProd:

```
${{github.ref == 'refs/heads/main' && github.event_name == 'push'}}
```

Workflow jobs seems to be running ok when code is merged, but not when a pull request is created.

Can someone point me what am I doing wrong ? I tried removing the line `types: [opened, reopened]`, but does not makes any difference.

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the answer.

Instead of
`if: $github.ref == 'refs/heads/dev' && github.event_name == 'pull_request'`

It should be
`if: $github.event.pull_request.base.ref == 'dev' && github.event_name == 'pull_request'`